# Leaks on iPhone, but not in Simulator, involving external libraries?

Tags: memory-leaks, ios-simulator

I need help with pinpointing source of leaks that all originate from external libraries, so I can't figure out if it's anything I'm doing.  Strangely, on the simulator there are no leaks!

Some of the Leaked Objects / Responsible libraries / ResponsibleFrames that show up are these:

```
UIImageView      iAd                -[ADBrandingFrame initWithFrame:]
CALayer          UIKit              -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
NSCFString       Foundation         -[NSCFString copyWithZone:]
GeneralBlock-88  QuartzCore        mem_alloc
GeneralBlock-32  ImageIO           ImageIO_Malloc
GeneralBlock-32  GraphicsServices  GSFontGetFullName
GeneralBlock-16  GraphicsServices  GSFontGetFamilyName
GeneralBlock-16  WebCore           RunWebThread(void*)
GeneralBlock-16  JavaScriptCore    WTF::initializeMainThreadPlatform()
```

WebCore and JavaScriptCore leaks are small leaks but among the first to show up.
The last one produces a backtrace like this one:

```
 0 libSystem.B.dylib thread_assign_default
 1 libSystem.B.dylib _pthread_start
 2 WebCore RunWebThread(void*)
 3 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
 4 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 5 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
 6 libSystem.B.dylib malloc
```

Any ideas out there as to what the problem may be?  I'd have a hard time believing that the leaks are all in the external libraries, but on the other hand no leaks show up in the Simulator.  Is there a bug in the Leaks application?  Should I not worry about these leaks?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason that the app doesn't show any leaks on your simulator is because the simulator uses your system's memory as its RAM, which itself is quite large.On the device the internal memory is very low depending upon the apps running,etc. So we can never track memory leaks on simulator as it never crashes.